# Forcing specific fields to be visible based on other fields' value

Tags: visualforce, flow

I am attempting to have my users answer several questions, and then having certain fields be visible or invisible based upon their answers to those questions.

One great solution I have been given would be to invoke a Flow which will lead them through the questions with screens, assign the variables to field values, and the reload the page in order to lead them through the questions.

However, I don't know how I would make certain fields appear based upon their answers. The obvious answer would be to use Record Types and different Page Layouts, but I have so many questions that it would be a ridiculous amount of Page Layouts in order to account for all of the different combinations of answers.

Is there any way to accomplish this outside of VisualForce ? I'm not a polished vet at VF so I really don't want to go that route if I don't have to. If that is the only route could you give me an example of how I would be able to accomplish that ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Other than VF pages, Flows are the best candidates for what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to go with a VisualForce page and in the rendered attribute of a specified field, write an inline if for example:

```
 <apex:inputField id="name" value="{!Object.Field}" rendered="{!IF(Object.Field == 'value',true,false)}"/>
```

You could google for more examples of if statements in the rendered attribute.

Comment: Mihai - thank you very much. I really appreciate the help !

One question : Would it work for me to just write a page for a specific section which would have the fields I am attempting to conditionally show and embed that page into the page layout - or do I need to do the entire page layout in VF ?

Comment: I think you should give it a try. As long as you are not relying on any custom controller to surface the data in your VF page, and use expressions like in my answer.